# String.split() won't work when reading from file

Tags: java, string, file, split, bufferedreader

I have to split a line read from a file, formatted like this:

```
NAME - Jane Doe
```

I tried using the split() method from String but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code

```
    String line=reader.readLine();

    while(line!=null) {

        String[] readLine = line.split("-");

        String label= readLine[0];
        String data = readLine[1];
        Sytem.out.println("My "+ label +" is " + data)

        line=reader.readLine();

    }
```

When I try to run it, it gives me a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
`String data = readLine[1];`
I tried some debugging and it seems like it doesn't split anything and just puts all the line in `String label= readLine[0];`.
I copy/pasted the same exact sentence outside the reading cycle and it splits perfectly. Any clue? Can the line change in any way when read from file? (Very unlikely, but it's obvious the problem is in there). Thank you in advance.

NOTE: it's not because there are spaces around the "-", it works fine anyway.

Comment: Maybe the sign is not a minus sign. Try to open your file with a hex editor and check it.

Comment: @Jens it is a minus sign, I wrote the file myself

Comment: What is the value of readLine[0] in that iteration when it comes to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException? Mybe you are in last empty line.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Maybe "-" is a special sign for regex. Try split("\\-").

Comment: @HectorLector Not here. Minus `-` it is only special character inside character class `[...]` where it represent range like `[a-z]`.

Comment: @Zigac it's the whole read line

Comment: It looks like the "-" minus sign is not in line of file.txt. Have you tried escaped string like @HectorLector suggested?

Comment: @Bianca could you please post the file content? this problem does not happen to me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code is running fine. As many already suggested there could be a problem with your file encoding. Using `string.split("-")` works for me. So no regex problem I would say.

Comment: @Zigac Escaping `-` can't help as it is not metacharacter there. It will just add more confusion.

Comment: Just to clearify line.contains("-") returns false?

Answer (score 0):

use
`'line.split("\\-") or line.split(Pattern.quote("-"))'` instead!